# Duplicate interface definition of class Parse

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, facebook-ios-sdk

I just updated my cocoa pods library and when I compile the project I am getting the error.

```
Duplicate interface definition of class Parse
```

Here is my Podfile

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
   use_frameworks!

  target 'Alfred' do
  pod 'Stripe'
  pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.7'
  pod 'Parse'
  pod 'ParseFacebookUtils'
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
  pod 'CMMapLauncher'
  pod 'Fabric'
  pod 'Crashlytics'
  pod 'SinchVerification', '0.9-beta1'
  pod 'TWMessageBarManager'
  pod 'MaterialControls', '~> 1.0.2'
  pod 'PubNub/Fabric'
 end
```

Any clue on this?

**Update**

This are the version of each library

```
Using Bolts (1.7.0)
Using CMMapLauncher (1.1.0)
Using CocoaLumberjack (2.2.0)
Using Crashlytics (3.7.0)
Using FBSDKCoreKit (4.10.1)
Using FBSDKLoginKit (4.10.1)
Using Fabric (1.6.7)
Using Facebook-iOS-SDK (3.24.4)
Using MaterialControls (1.0.2)
Using Parse (1.13.0)
Using ParseFacebookUtils (1.10.0)
Using PubNub (4.3.0)
Using SDWebImage (3.7.5)
Using SinchVerification (0.9-beta1)
Using Stripe (6.2.0)
Using TWMessageBarManager (1.8.1)
```

Comment: have you tried to clean the project and delete the derived data and build again?

Comment: Like four times already

Comment: what was the update after which you started to get this error? Please list all changes here.

Comment: Using Bolts (1.7.0)
Using CMMapLauncher (1.1.0)
Using CocoaLumberjack (2.2.0)
Using Crashlytics (3.7.0)
Using FBSDKCoreKit (4.10.1)
Using FBSDKLoginKit (4.10.1)
Using Fabric (1.6.7)
Using Facebook-iOS-SDK (3.24.4)
Using MaterialControls (1.0.2)
Using Parse (1.13.0)
Using ParseFacebookUtils (1.10.0)
Using PubNub (4.3.0)
Using SDWebImage (3.7.5)
Using SinchVerification (0.9-beta1)
Using Stripe (6.2.0)
Using TWMessageBarManager (1.8.1)

Comment: @noir_eagle I updated my question with more details

Comment: as I know `ParseFacebookUtils` is deprecated. 
Try to use `ParseFacebookUtilsV4` instead

Answer (score 2):

Ok I fixed it this way:

for objC 
just remove use_frameworks! or comment it #use_frameworks!
then clean, build, and run..